# CGAL: Polygon overlap test

Tags: c++, cgal

I am looking for a function which tests whether in 2D a simple polygon completely contains another simple polygon. `do_intersect` as mentioned [here](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Boolean_set_operations_2/group__boolean__do__intersect.html#ga77d2088ac95f168918a03913bd9366a6), returns true even if polygons are partially overlapping. What is the appropriate function to check complete overlap?

Comment: Not sure what the exact capabiliites of cgal are, but things that could work: is the symmetric difference of the polygons equal to their difference? Or is the intersection of the polygons equal to the second polygon?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `do_intersect()` function first and if you have no intersection take any point for P1 and check whether it is inside P2 using [`has_on_bounded_side()`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon/classCGAL_1_1Polygon__2.html#aed22a0e432f6f3fa503ed1e06ec188f5). Then if P1 is not included in P2, do same for a point of P2 with reference to P1 in order to conclude.

Answer (score 0):

A  convex polygon is completely contained in another convex polygon if and only all its vertices are contained inside the containing polygon.

To test if a point is contained inside the polygon you can use the OpenCV function pointPolygonTest() ([see description here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=pointpolygontest#pointpolygontest)) ([see example use here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/point_polygon_test/point_polygon_test.html))

Comment: I am looking for a solution in CGAL context though.

Comment: Can't you use something from https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Point_set_2/index.html#Chapter_2D_Range_and_Neighbor_Search ?

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but to give an answer but for posterity's sake. You need to loop through the points of the polygon and check if they are on the bounded side

```
\\Assuming that CGAL::Polygon_2 type is used
typedef CGAL::Polygon_2<Kernel>                         Polygon_2;

bool do_overlap(Polygon_2 inner_polygon, Polygon_2 outer_polygon) {
    //Check if the innner_polygon vertices are all on the bounded side of the outer_polygon
    for (auto vertex_it = inner_polygon.vertices_begin(); vertex_it != inner_polygon.vertices_end(); ++vertex_it) {
        if (outer_polygon.bounded_side(*vertex_it) != CGAL::ON_BOUNDED_SIDE) {
            //First point found of the inner_polygon outside the outer_polygon is enough to say it is not completly inside.
            return false;
        }
    }
    //If no points outside are found the inner_polygon must be completely inside the outer_polygon.
    return true
}
```

With this function, you only check if the inner_polygon is inside the outer_polygon and not the other way around, but you get the gist.